# Implementing Remember Me function in Laravel 4 returns an error

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, controller, laravel-4

I'm trying to implement a `Remember Me` function using Laravel 4.

But I'm getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException syntax
>
> error, unexpected ','

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    if(Auth::guest())
    {
        return View::make('login'); 
    }
    else
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }
});

Route::post('/', 'UserController@Login');
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function Login() {
    $credentials = array(
      'username' => Input::get('username'),
      'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    $remember = Input::has('remember-me') ? true : false;

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials), $remember) {
      return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    else {
      return 'fail';
    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
>
> …/­app/­controllers/­UserController.php13
>
> Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown <#unknown>0

Line 13 is

`if(Auth::attempt($credentials), $remember)`

Comment: Please post exact error message with line number and the line that is causing the error.

Comment: @edvinas.me : Please check the edit I have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials), $remember) {
```

to

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
```

The closing bracket for `Auth::attempt()` was misplaced. Now it should work.